# С - что значит выражение?

Tags: c

Помогите разобраться с выражением. Мы создали тип данных структура с алиасом WORKER.
А что происходит дальше - WORKER *base = malloc(itter * sizeof *base)? Мы инициализируем переменную base и присваиваем ей значение размера через указатель *base ?

```
int main(){
    typedef struct{
        char* fio;
        char* staff;
        int year;
    }WORKER;
    int itter=3, x;    
    //?
    WORKER *base = malloc(itter * sizeof *base);
```

Comment: `sizeof * base` - это размер типа структуры в байтах, на которой указывает указатель `base`. Что равносильно `sizeof WORKER`. Функция `malloc` выделяет память нужного количества байт, где `itter * sizeof WORKER` - означает для трёх структур.

Comment: выделение памяти под 3 элемента структуры WORKER.